# In ggplot2, how to add figures table to the plot image

Tags: r, ggplot2

In R/ggplot2, how to combine 'table' and 'plot' ?
As below, i want to add the 'data_table' to the ggplot2 image.
(the result just as attached image which combine by manual)
Anyone can help ? Thanks!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gcookbook)
library(plyr)
library(formattable)
ce<-arrange(cabbage_exp,Date,Cultivar)

data_table <- formattable(ce)

data_plot <- ggplot(ce,aes(x=Date ,y=Weight,fill=Cultivar))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity')+
  geom_text(vjust=1,aes(label=Weight),position='stack')
```

[image]

Comment: try https://ggobi.github.io/ggally/articles/ggtable.html

Comment: @mzuba  thanks for your replay , I refered the link  but still can't solve it